# How to do MySQL order by x where (x=col3 if col3!=null, else x=col2)?

Tags: mysql

Suppose, a select operation is giving 3 columns: col1, col2 and col3. col2 and col3 are of type time. I want the result to order by the time-stamp. For each record, time-stamp is equal to col3 if col3 is Not null, else it's col2. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in function [`ifnull()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```
select
...
order by ifnull(col3, col2)
```

`ifnull()` returns the first parameter if it is not null, otherwise the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using subqueries. In the internal query you check if col3 is NULL and you "select" col3 or col2 AS "my_time". And then, in the external query, you order by "my_time".

Sub-query example:

```
SELECT <whatever>, IF (col3 IS NOT NULL, col3, col2) AS my_time FROM <table>
```

And then, the external query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT <whatever>, IF (col3 IS NOT NULL, col3, col2) AS my_time FROM <table>
) AS <temp_table> ORDER BY <temp_table>.my_time
```